# Como substituir determinada sentença de uma string em Python? Utilizando o re.sub()

Tags: python, regex

Gostaria de substituir toda expressão que inicie com os caracteres: `*:`.

```
tentativa = 'Olá td bem? *:palavra_proibida*985 td otimo'
resultado = re.sub('*:', '', tentativa)
```

Resultado Obtido:

```
Olá td bem? palavra_proibida*985 td otimo
```

Resultado esperado:

```
Olá td bem? td otimo
```

Comment: "sentença" não seria frase ? o numero é sempre 985 ou pode ser outro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> tentativa = 'Olá td bem? *:palavra_proibida*985 td otimo'
>>> resultado = re.sub(r'\*:\S+', '', tentativa)
>>> print(resultado)
Olá td bem?  td otimo
```

Esse código usa o `\S+` que quer dizer "1 ou mais caracteres que não são espaço"; Significa que ele vai substituir tudo que vier depois de `*:` até encontrar o primeiro espaço.

Note que acrescentei também uma barra antes do `*` para "escapar" o comportamento especial que o `*` tem em expressões regulares - com a barra ele será tratado somente como um asterisco normal a ser localizado.